# Comparing .txt files and getting the difference

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare two text files `a.txt` and `b.txt`, I want to get the difference between the two.
`a.txt` is the result from yesterday.
`b.txt` is the current result.
The tricky thing is that I wonna find out what is missing in "b.txt" compared to "a.txt" even tho there might have been added something new in "b.txt", these new objects needs to be excluded.
The two files is not ordered so what is in index 1 in 'a.txt' can be index 2 in 'b.txt'. I'm comparing string like "mano - mathias rønnow nørtoft". 

All I had tried just ends up displaying the new objects aswell.
What I've tried:

```
 string[] File1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
 string[] File2Lines = File.ReadAllLines(newPath);
 List<string> NewLines = new List<string>();

for (int lineNo = 0; lineNo<File1Lines.Length; lineNo++)
  {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(File1Lines[lineNo]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(File2Lines[lineNo]))
    {
      if(String.Compare(File1Lines[lineNo], File2Lines[lineNo]) != 0)
        NewLines.Add(File2Lines[lineNo]) ;
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(File1Lines[lineNo]))
    {
    }
    else
    {
      NewLines.Add(File2Lines[lineNo]);
    }
  }
  if (NewLines.Count > 0)
  {
    File.WriteAllLines(resultpath, NewLines);
  }
```

This just gives me the file merged. Hope I've explained my self correctly.

tried this, why is that not working? it displays nothing.

```
        List<string> a = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
        List<string> b = File.ReadAllLines(newPath).ToList();

        List<string> copy = new List<string>(a);

        foreach (string s in copy)
        {
            if (b.Contains(s))
            {
                a.Remove(s);

            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        myWriter.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: Your code relies on line numbers essentially being in sync between the two files, which is a fairly major assumption. You need to clarify what the unit is you are comparing - lines? characters? and also whereabouts in each file items can be added or removed - at any arbitrary place in either file? Also are two occurences of a specific unit treated as one thing or two things? etc etc. It's not trivial!

Comment: Diffing files is an open-ended and very difficult problem, however it has been solved in the past. I suggest you use an existing library instead of reimplementing it yourself (unless this is an academic exercise). For example, DiffPlex: https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel.  Why?  If you really insist on re-implementing it then look for established algorithms such as the Myers algorithm used by the `diff` utility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Algorithm

Comment: i've updated the question. I'm gonna take a look at that Dai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on how accurate you want the diff to be and how fast you want it to be.

An easy implementation would be to get all lines of both A and B, foreach line in A, if B contains that line then remove that line from both A and B once. What's left would be the lines in A but not in B or wise versa.

Note that this method does not take ordering into consideration, so

```
Log 1  
C   
B   
A
```

and

```
Log 2  
A  
B   
C
```

are considered identical.

```
List<string> A;
List<string> B;

List<string> aCopy = new List(A);

foreach(string s in aCopy)
{
    if (B.Contains(s))
    {
        A.Remove(s);
        B.Remove(s);
    }
}

//Whats in A are whats missing in B
//Whats in B are whats missing in A
```

Comment: This is just what i need Steve, do you mind giving me an example?

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft code not tested. just to show idea

Comment: Steve one more favor, ive edited my question. Any ideas of why its not working?

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft should be foreach(string s in a) ...WriteLine(s);

Comment: yeah tried that, it was a brain fart. i didnt close the writer after. thanks for your time! youre a god to me

Answer (score 1):

You can join , sort  and remove the equality string with a regex command

```
 using System;

    using System.Text;


     using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   class Program


{

 static void Main()

{

    string strFile4xf = File.ReadAllText(@"a.txt");

    strFile4xf = Regex.Replace(    strFile4xf,     @"(.*?)\r", "$1a\r");
   File.WriteAllText(@"a1.txt", strFile4xf);



    string strFile4xe = File.ReadAllText(@"b.txt");

      strFile4xe = Regex.Replace(    strFile4xe,     @"(.*?)\r", "$1b\r");
   File.WriteAllText(@"b1.txt", strFile4xe);





        string s4 = File.ReadAllText(@"a1.txt"); 

   string s2 = File.ReadAllText(@"b1.txt"); 

  string sn = string.Concat(s4, s2);

  File.WriteAllText(@"join.txt", sn);

  var contents = File.ReadAllLines("join.txt");
       Array.Sort(contents);
    File.WriteAllLines("join.txt", contents);

     string strFile4x = File.ReadAllText(@"join.txt");

   strFile4x = Regex.Replace(    strFile4x,     @"\n(.*?)a\r\n\1b\r", "");
     File.WriteAllText(@"removeequal.txt", strFile4x);




   var contents2 = File.ReadAllLines("removeequal.txt");
       Array.Sort(contents2);
    File.WriteAllLines("removeequal.txt", contents2);




string strFile4x2 = File.ReadAllText(@"removeequal.txt");

 strFile4x2 = Regex.Replace(    strFile4x,     @"\n\r", "");
 File.WriteAllText(@"blanklines.txt", strFile4x2);


     }
  }
```

this command match the repeat string \n(.*?)\r\n\1\r  when this is sorted

Comment: This works, ive got one error though, i just tried having to identical texts, and one string which is in them both, popped up. and in "blanklines.txt" it is mentioned twice. the texts are like 100 lines long, so wierd it gives an error at 1 line only?

Comment: I do not understand very well what is the problem
could explain it better? (inside you question)

Comment: this command only remove equal lines  \n(.*?)\r\n\1\r

Comment: Yeah sorry i didnt explain myself well enough, i need to check the files and whatever lines match i need them to be deleted from "a.txt". So i can check which lines was there "yesterday" but not today. If you know what i mean?

Comment: "b.txt" can have new lines that are not relevant. but i wanna check which lines are missing from the day before "a.txt".